# Check user role with meteor react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, meteor

Within a meteor web application, you can check the role of a user using [alanning:roles](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles). How to i check the role of that particular user when implementing it on react native using [react-native-meteor](https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-meteor) for mine react-native application.

Comment: Afaik does `alanning:roles` not rely on Meteor methods, which means you could use it with `react-native-meteor` too.

Comment: @Jankapunkt yes that is the best solution I can think of. i.e calling a method to which should return the role of the user from the meteor server.